# Adding custom html code to Android Webview

Tags: android, html, webview, assets

I am rendering website which is not mine and has a lot of server side scripts(so I cannot save it as html page to use). I want to make my android webview to execute these html code as well.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Is there any way to inject it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call load url that contains html code. See [DOM Manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) here.